# SelectList dropdown gets Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, drop-down-menu

I am new to react-Native and building my first app. I tried to add a dropdown where options will be coming from database. it displays properly but when I select, I receive the error below.

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
> You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
> See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

not sure what is wrong with my code, sometimes I also get errors like

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setSelected

```
// components/AddUsersScreen.js
import { Component, useState } from 'react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Alert, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import firebase from '../database/firebaseDb';
//css
import { styles } from "../css/Styles";
//
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox'
import SelectDropdown from 'react-native-select-dropdown'

import { SelectList } from 'react-native-dropdown-select-list'

export default class AddUsersScreen extends Component { 
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.dbRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users');
    this.firestoreRef = firebase.firestore().collection('household');
    this.state = { 
      displayName : '',
      lastname: '',
      email: '',
      phoneNumber: '',
      password:'',
      householdId : '',
      active : '',
      uid: '',
      roleId : '',
    }
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState("");   
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.unsubscribe = this.firestoreRef.onSnapshot(this.getCollection);
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  getCollection = (querySnapshot) => {

    const householdArr = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((res) => {
    const {householdName} = res.data();   
      householdArr.push({
        householdId: res.id,
        householdName
      });
    });

    this.setState({
      householdArr,
      isLoading: false,
   });

  const householdOptions = householdArr.map(d => ({
     "key" : d.householdId,
     "value" : d.householdName

   }))
   
   this.setState({selectOptions: householdOptions})

  }
  
  updateInputVal = (val, prop) => {
    const state = this.state;
    state[prop] = val;
    this.setState(state);
  }
  storeUser = () => {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
    });
    console.log('here')
    this.dbRef.doc(this.userDetails.uid).set({
      displayName : this.userDetails.displayName,
      lastname: this.userDetails.lastname,
      email:this.userDetails.email,
      phoneNumber: this.userDetails.phoneNumber,
      householdId : this.userDetails.householdId, 
      roleId : this.userDetails.roleId,
      active : this.userDetails.active,
      uid: this.userDetails.uid
        }).then((res) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            displayName : '',
            lastname: '',
            email: '',
            phoneNumber: '',
            password:'',
            householdId : '', 
            roleId : '',
            active : '',
            uid: ''
          });
        })
        console.log("added")      
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error("Error found: ", err);
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
          });
        });

      }
      
  registerUser = () => {
    if(this.state.email === '' || this.state.password === '' || this.state.displayName === '' || this.state.phoneNumber === '' || this.state.password === '') {
      Alert.alert('Enter all details!')
    }if(this.state.password.length < 6){
      Alert.alert('Password should be more than 6 characters!')
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: true
      })
      firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then((res) => {
        res.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: this.state.displayName,
          phoneNumber: this.state.phoneNumber
        })
        console.log('User registered successfully! UID : ' +  res.user.uid)
        this.userDetails = {
          displayName : this.state.displayName,
          lastname: this.state.lastname,
          email:this.state.email,
          phoneNumber: this.state.phoneNumber,
          householdId : '', 
          roleId : 2,
          active : 1,
          uid: res.user.uid
        }
        this.storeUser();                
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          displayName : '',
          lastname: '',
          email: '',
          password:'',
          phoneNumber: '',
          householdId : '', 
          roleId : '',
          active : '',
          uid: ''
        })
      })
      .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }))      
    }
  }
  render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={styles.preloader}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#d00"/>
        </View>
      )
    }    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>  
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputStyle}
          placeholder="First Name"
          value={this.state.displayName}
          onChangeText={(val) => this.updateInputVal(val, 'displayName')}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputStyle}
          placeholder="Last Name"
          onChangeText={(val) => this.updateInputVal(val, 'lastname')}
        />                
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputStyle}
          placeholder="Email"
          value={this.state.email}
          onChangeText={(val) => this.updateInputVal(val, 'email')}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputStyle}
          placeholder="Phone Number"
          value={this.state.mobile}
          onChangeText={(val) => this.updateInputVal(val, 'phoneNumber')}
          maxLength={15}
        /> 
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputStyle}
          placeholder="Password"
          value={this.state.password}
          onChangeText={(val) => this.updateInputVal(val, 'password')}
          maxLength={15}
          secureTextEntry={true}
        /> 
       <SelectList 
        placeholder='Select Household'
        setSelected={(val) => setSelected(val)}
        data={this.state.selectOptions} 
        save="key"
        search={false}
    />
      <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}> 
      <Text style={styles.buttons} onPress={() => this.registerUser()}>Add User</Text>
      <Text style={styles.buttons} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('UserListsScreen')}>Back to Users List</Text>                                 
      </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried some other Select Dropdown but this is the one that is actually somehow working. I am not sure what is the issue with the hooks.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use react hooks inside class component that's why it is giving you error.